# Scheduling of a RPA process

Tags: python, monitoring, scheduling, rpa

How can we set scheduling of a RPA process. 
Though I know we can set windows Task scheduler to schedule a RPA process but is there any way instead of setting scheduling it in Task Scheduler. Is there any workflow or can we design some custom protocol in which scheduling is set on deployment server and RPA process runs on specific local system.
I know UiPath, Automagica etc are doing this but don't know how they are doing this.
Can we use socket for this. Can we use some RMM (Remote monitoring and management) software like Atera for this.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more R&D, I come to a resolution that Client-Server architecture using sockets is best suited approach for above mentioned requirement.
For python we can use python-socketio library which is python implementation of actual javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

in #UiPath only way is orchestrator.
In case of RDA you can get notification from robot tray at the time you want to run.
in earlier version RDA process can schedule with window scheduler but in 2019 they stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule your process by the below way:

1. Through the scheduler in the Orchestrator
2. Through the queue: if any transaction gets added to the queue, then the respective process will get triggered called as Queue Based Trigger
3. With the help of windows scheduler also we can schedule a process.

Cheers!!